# Rails: no such file to load -- action_dispatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, installation

I cannot start my server, it really doesn't make sense.  Traced the paths, found the gems, install, uninstalled, re-installed, and nothing seems to work. Installed on OS X via RVM.  So here's the stats:
    $ which ruby
    /Users/Ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby

```
$ which rails
/Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rails

$ which gem
/Users/Ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem

$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.1.3)
actionpack (3.1.3)
activemodel (3.1.3)
activerecord (3.1.3)
activeresource (3.1.3)
activesupport (3.1.3)
arel (2.2.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
json (1.6.4)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.0.4)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.3.6)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.1.3)
railties (3.1.3)
rake (0.9.2.2 ruby, 0.8.7)
rdoc (3.12)
rubygems-update (1.8.15)
sprockets (2.0.3)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.31)

$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/Ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
     - /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Update 12/16/12-=>

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
require 'rubygems'

gem 'rails'
gem 'actionpack'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml'
gem "devise", :git => "https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git"
# gem 'oa-core'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-openid'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-github'
gem "settingslogic"
gem 'composite_primary_keys'
gem 'addressable'
gem 'faraday'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'squeel'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.6'
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'hpricot', :require => false #html2haml
  gem 'ruby_parser', :require => false # html2haml
  gem 'pickle'
  gem 'awesome_print', :require => 'ap'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'heroku', :require => false
  gem 'sass'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.0.rc3'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

Comment: Can you post the Gemfile for the app in question? Have you run `bundle install` for the app?

Comment: yes I have run bundle install, I'll update to add the Gemfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was a security conflict; I had to chown all the file in the gems directory.  The owner was root and unless I wanted to sudo the server, I just need my user to have rights to all the files