# rails 4 can't start server after upgrading to rails 4 from rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

After upgrading from rails 3 to rails 4 I am unable to start it locally. This is just on my computer since other dev who work with me don't experience this. 
I also had to uninstall and install again ruby 2.1.2 since apparently it was installed under root (now it's under my username).

```
$ bundle exec rails s
/Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- action_dispatch (LoadError)
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `require'
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `require_command!'
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:74:in `server'
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I am also unable to load my console

```
$ bundle exec rails c
/Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support (LoadError)
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Volumes/fiverr_dev/5rr_v2/config/application.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Volumes/fiverr_dev/5rr_v2/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require'
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project_gemset/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'


bundle install
Using rake 10.3.2
Using aasm 3.4.0
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.4.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.1.6
.....
```

Comment: Try a `bundle install`. And confirm. Also post your Gemfile.

Comment: bundle install works, added part of it's output. notice the activesupport without the '_'

Comment: Great but post what is in your gemfile. Or for now, comment out activesupport and try booting the server again.

Comment: @Sylar activesupport is a part of rails. it's not the issue here

Comment: Try to execute `rake rails:update:bin`

Comment: @WebQube once check whether ruby version is 2.1.2 from the directory where you are starting the server or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bunch of solutions,
Reinstalling worked

rvm get stable

rvm gemset delete fiverr_v2

bundle install

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions, may be you don't have necessary to read the file - you say that initially ruby was installed under root, so may be you didn't fix it completely (eg. here's the same problem [Rails: no such file to load -- action_dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857458/rails-no-such-file-to-load-action-dispatch)). Try running `rails s` under root, if it works then the reason is found.